# TypeScript/JavaScript in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm a beginner level in writing in TypeScript and working with Angular, but I am experienced in JavaScript. From what I've read, any TypeScript would be translated into JavaScript and compiled. So when I code in the TypeScript file (e.g. the whatever.component.ts file), does that mean I can mix or introduce JavaScript language code inside where I also write TypeScript in the .ts file?

How does this all exist within the .ts file in regards to a code readability aspect for someone who is just learning TypeScript/Angular?

Comment: yup, typescript is super set of javascript, i.e. any javascript code is valid typescript code (with possible type warnings though).

Comment: Yes you can. Type script is a super set of java script. Ts allow completely js

Answer (score 3):

You can of course use JavaScript anyhow you like it. However, TypeScript is built to help the developers maintaining projects by using variables types. The types can then easily be read and previewed by good IDE with the appropriate extensions.

Get used to adding types. Use interfaces for custom objects, embrace the Angular way and you will forget you ever had to deal with JavaScript very soon.

A good base for productive IDE would be Visual Studio Code with the Angular Essentials extension.

Welcome to the Angular community!